# Ошибка в конфигурационном файле servlet-context.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

При запуске проекта на сервере возвращает ошибку

> HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>
> message Error instantiating servlet class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.

servlet-context.xml

```
    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/appContext.xml"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Слишком мало информации для того, чтобы вам помочь.

Comment: P.S. Что в логах? Если ничего, то включите дебаг и снова смотрите в логи.